# Regex to match dollar sign and following spaces

Tags: regex

As the title says, I need to create a regex that matches `$` and any following space after it. Example:

```
"asd $   5" should match "$   ".
```

Is is possible? I could find anything like that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
[$]\s+
```

`[$]` will match the dollar sign, and `\s+` will match one or more spaces after the dollar sign.

See test example here: https://regex101.com/r/Y4j98L/1

Comment: Take care that `\s` matches also vertical spaces, depending on wwhat is really wanted you may use `\h` instead (for horizontal spaces). Nevertheless, +1

Answer (score 3):

For the dollar sign, you need to escape the sign. So `\$\s*` would match what you want. I interpret "any matching spaces" as there being a possibility of there being no spaces as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get with **\$\s+**

Make sure to put escape character before $ since $ also indicates end of string in regex